# The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing ')' formula error in process builder

Tags: process-builder, formula, error, record-type, salesforcedx-cli

i AM CREATING A PROCESS BUILDER WITH CONDITIONS AS FOLLOWS
Residential / Commercial: Sales  //THESE ARE ME RECORD TYPES

Contact Type: Investor, End User or Buyer //MULTIPICKLIST
Stage: Past Client  //PICKLIST

Create New Valuation (property owner) Contact(WHERE NEW VALUATION IS MY RECORD TYPE) – Assign to the same contact owner

I created a below formula for criterial to be checked but I am getting error The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'INCLUDES()'. Expected 2, received 4

AND( OR( [Contact].RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Commercial – Sales' ,
[Contact].RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Residential – Sales'
),
ISPICKVAL([Contact].pba__Stage_pb__c , "Lost Client") ,
INCLUDES([Contact].pba__ContactType_pb__c,'Investor', 'Buyer', 'End User')
)

Please help me out .how to create a formula with aboove conditions specified

Answer (score 0):

If you format it like this:

```
AND( OR( [Contact].RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Commercial – Sales' , 
         [Contact].RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Residential – Sales' 
       ), 
     ISPICKVAL([Contact].pba__Stage_pb__c , "Lost Client") , 
     OR (INCLUDES([Contact].pba__ContactType_pb__c,'Investor'),
         INCLUDES([Contact].pba__ContactType_pb__c,'Buyer'),
         INCLUDES([Contact].pba__ContactType_pb__c,'End User')
     )
   )
```

You can much more easily debug it. I noticed a missing comma - it's been added and this should compile correctly.

Comment: I fixed an issue - includes can't have params the way you had them - I just assumed it was a shorthand format. I've replaced with an `OR()` containing the includes you are checking for.